# Como desagrupar dados com o pandas?

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, pandas, powerbi

Trabalho com um banco de dados que utiliza frequência, e quero desagrupar os dados de frequência e transformar em várias linhas. Segue imagem exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero fazer com que a linha 6, por exemplo, se transforme em 6 linhas iguais com os mesmos dados. Pensei em "reescrever" a planilha toda e salvar como um novo porque pode ser que só modificar as linhas dê algum problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o que você busca pode ser alcançado com `reindex` e `repeat`:

```
df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df.FREQUENCIA))
```

Infelizmente não tenho como demonstrar a saida dos dados porque você subiu uma imagem como amostra e eu não tenho como "copiar" os dados dessa forma

Comment: Muito obrigado, era exatamente isso. Tô extremamente feliz que deu certo hahaha um adianto de vida e tanto!